# Dynamic field name in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openerp-7

I work with openerp7.0 and in openerp we use Python. In Python, we declare an attribute like the following:

```
'dashboard_borne1':fields.float("0-10",digits=(12,0)),
```

After that, when we want to show the table that contains the attributes we write the following code in XML:

```
<field name="dashboard_borne1"/>
```

so the table will be showed and the column dashboard_borne1 will have 0-10 like a label(Title of the column).
I want that the label take what the user insert in the input. For example if he insert "50-100" the label take "50-100" so i want that the field have a dynamic name. is it possible in Python? any idea please?

Comment: Where would you like to insert the range? Maybe it would be a good idea create two fields, one for the label and another for the content

Comment: Hi ChesuCR it is a good idea but this is not possible in OpenERP, because in the table we must insert the name of the field

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output.

Comment: Ah! You are working in a tree view. But where would you like to insert the value? Directly in the column or in a separated form?

Comment: Thats it, in the column ;)

Comment: Uuh I think that's complex. You would have to build a widget in javascript to override the tree view to add a new box and when you change the value of the column you would have to change the string attribute of the column. And maybe that would imply update the translations records as well

Comment: I think you should keep to the Odoo framework as much as possible